# HttpContext.Current.Session returns null when used in a utility class (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, null, httpcontext

So I created a static extension class to provide extension methods for DateTime objects. I followed this tutorial in order to solve a timezone issue: http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/how_to_display_dates_and_times_in_clients_timezone

Problem is that my utility class isn't within a controller and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session is null, and I don't want to have to pass the context as a parameter every time since I need to use it in various locations as well.

Is there any way to pass the session to an outside class?

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement this interface in your code.  It works for handlers.

```
System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

Comment: This is not enough, there's something else to the picture here.